# низкоуровневое программирование на Python: статус аккумулятора ноутбука

Tags: python, ноутбук

Я как-то загорелся желанием написать простую программульку на Python. Которая например узнавала статус аккумулятора ноутбука и т. п. Но вот незадача. Python это высокоуровневый язык. Может где-нибудь есть модуль написанный на C который поможет мне с этой задачей. Посоветуйте пожалуйста такие модули, чем больше - тем лучше!

Comment: Узнавание статуса аккумулятора ноутбука является очень высокоуровневой задачей — всего лишь к API операционной системы обратиться. Например, в линуксе достаточно прочитать файлы из каталога типа `/sys/class/power_supply/BATx`

Comment: я привёл пример. Может например регулировка скорости вращения кулера

Comment: Одна из сложностей низкоуровневого программирования - намного меньшее количество универсальных решений. Под каждую задачу для каждой операционной системы придётся искать свой подход. Ищите подходящее системное API или библиотеки и используйте их. Например с помощью [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Переносимый код для получения информации о статусе батареи и много другого можно получить с помощью [psutil модуля](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.sensors_battery):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
>>> battery
sbattery(percent=93, secsleft=16628, power_plugged=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Адаптация ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/21083571/5909792.

---

Можно использовать функцию WinApi [GetSystemPowerStatus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getsystempowerstatus) и создав структуру [_SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ns-winbase-_system_power_status):

```
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_byte, c_ulong, byref

class _SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('ACLineStatus', c_byte),
        ('BatteryFlag', c_byte),
        ('BatteryLifePercent', c_byte),
        ('Reserved1', c_byte),
        ('BatteryLifeTime', c_ulong),
        ('BatteryFullLifeTime', c_ulong)
    ]

system_power_status = _SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS()
result = windll.kernel32.GetSystemPowerStatus(byref(system_power_status))
print(system_power_status.BatteryLifePercent)
```

---

Можно использовать технологию [WMI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WMI).

Через модуль `wmi`:

```
# pip install wmi
import wmi

w = wmi.WMI()
for battery in w.query('select * from Win32_Battery'):
    print(battery.EstimatedChargeRemaining)
```

Через модуль `pywin32`:

```
# pip install pywin32
from win32com.client import GetObject

WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')
for battery in WMI.InstancesOf('Win32_Battery'):
    print(battery.EstimatedChargeRemaining)
```

---

**PS.**

Минус в том, что эти варианты работают только с Windows. Если хотите поддержать другие ОС, придется добавить код для другой ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Этот Модуль работает только на ноутбуках.

```
from ctypes import Structure, wintypes, POINTER, windll, pointer, WinError

def batteryCharge():
   """ АККУМУЛЯТОРНАЯ ФУНКЦИЯ """
   class SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS(Structure):
       _fields_ = [
           ("ACLineStatus",       wintypes.BYTE),
           ("BatteryFlag",        wintypes.BYTE),
           ("BatteryLifePercent", wintypes.BYTE),
           ]

   SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_P = POINTER(SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS)

   GetSystemPowerStatus          = windll.kernel32.GetSystemPowerStatus
   GetSystemPowerStatus.argtypes = [SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_P]
   GetSystemPowerStatus.restype  = wintypes.BOOL

   status = SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS()
   if not GetSystemPowerStatus(pointer(status)):
      raise WinError()

   charging, charge = status.ACLineStatus, status.BatteryLifePercent
   return (charging, charge)


def batteryStatus():
   """ СТАТУС ФУНКЦИЯ """
   chargingCharge = batteryCharge()
   charging       = chargingCharge[0]
   charge         = chargingCharge[1]

   if charging == 0:
      print("\nАккумулятор не получает заряд.")
      if charge <= 15:
         print("Заряд батареи ниже или равен 15%.")
      else:
         print("Зарядка аккумулятора: {}%.".format(charge))
   elif charging == 1:
      print("\nАккумулятор получает заряд.")
      print("Зарядка аккумулятора: {}%.\n".format(charge))
   else:
      print("\nЭта система работает только на ноутбуках.")


# ФУНКЦИЯ ВЫЗОВА
batteryStatus()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ESTADO_ENERGIA_SISTEMA_P` это португальский что ли? :D Функция GetSystemPowerStatus принимает тип с названием LPSYSTEM_POWER_STATUS: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getsystempowerstatus

Answer (score 0):

ioctl в линуксах используется, в виндовс winapi. напрямую работать с батарейкой не стоит того. работайте на высоком уровне с операционной системой

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/340643)

Comment: @freim какой вопрос такой и ответ